# How to get the FolderPath in MFC application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, header-files, folderbrowserdialog

I am using visual studio 2008...I am tryin to get the folder path for my output file in my design ...I know there is a class called CFolderDialog ..but its not working in my pgm..should I include any header file inorder to get that..if YES,can anybody tell me how to include in visual studio 2008..plz help me

Comment: In what manner is it not working?  Please give some more detail, for example compiler error.  And perhaps show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the CFolderdialog..instead of that..iam using another to get the folder path...check my code below....am getting a run time error when i try toprint the folder path name in  a edit box..

void CSelfExtractorUIDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

```
CDialog dlg;

HWND hwnd = NULL;
LPCTSTR szCurrent = (LPCTSTR)malloc(25*sizeof(TCHAR));
szCurrent = NULL;
LPTSTR szPath = (LPTSTR)malloc(25*sizeof(TCHAR));
BOOL check = BrowseForFolder(hwnd,szCurrent,szPath);
if( check == TRUE)
{
    dlg.SetDlgItemTextW(IDC_EDIT1,szPath);
}
```

}

BOOL BrowseForFolder(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR szCurrent, LPTSTR szPath)
{
    BROWSEINFO   bi = { 0 };
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
    TCHAR        szDisplay[256];
    BOOL         retval;

```
//CoInitialize();

bi.hwndOwner      = hwnd;
bi.pszDisplayName = szDisplay;
bi.lpszTitle      = TEXT("Please choose a folder.");
bi.ulFlags        = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE;
bi.lpfn           = BrowseCallbackProc;
bi.lParam         = (LPARAM) szCurrent;

pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

if (NULL != pidl)
{
    retval = SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, szPath);
    CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
}
else
{
    retval = FALSE;
}

if (!retval)
{
    szPath[0] = TEXT('\0');
}

CoUninitialize();
return retval;
```

}
static int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData)
{
    // If the BFFM_INITIALIZED message is received
    // set the path to the start path.
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case BFFM_INITIALIZED:
        {
            if (NULL != lpData)
            {
                SendMessage(hwnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, TRUE, lpData);
            }
        }
    }

```
return 0; // The function should always return 0.
```

}